# does git ls-files print files in the current working directory

Tags: git

I was told that `git ls-files` print files in the current working directory. Let's say I have a directory called MyFolder, then I created a new file `HelloWorld.cs`(and I did't use `git add` to add this file), then I run `git ls-files` and it didn't display `HelloWorld.cs`. But technically speaking, `HelloWorld.cs` is in the current working directory(MyFolder), so why it didn't get displayed?

Comment: I recommend running `git ls-files --help`

Answer (score 1):

`git ls-files` is a moderately complicated command, with multiple different modes, so the answer to the subject-line question:

> does git ls-files print files in the current working directory

is both no and yes.

> I was told that git ls-files print files in the current working directory.

Sometimes it does, and sometimes it doesn't.  As [Keith Thompson commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180269/does-git-ls-files-print-files-in-the-current-working-directory#comment106443188_60180269), you should read [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)—but Git documentation is notable for being impenetrable, full of jargon and so obscure that [fake Git manual pages](https://git-man-page-generator.lokaltog.net/) are hard to tell from real ones.

The overall job of `git ls-files` is to deal with files that are and/or are not in Git's *index*.  The index is a complicated Git internal entity that Git foists upon all users.  It itself is so important and/or obscure and/or poorly named that it actually has *three* names in Git: Git calls it the *index* sometimes, but the *staging area* other times.  The third name, the *cache*, is not as common today, but you will still see it sometimes.

The index has a lot of roles, but its main one—the one you should know about at all times—is that it is where you (and Git) build the *next* commit you intend to make.  What the index contains consists mainly of copies<sup>1</sup> of files.  Each of these copies has a *name*—a path name relative to the top level of the repository, such as `README.md` or `top/mid/file.ext`—and some *content:* a snapshot of a file.  There is also a *mode bit*, which for regular files is just a single bit—it can only take on one of two values—but for various reasons is spelled out as either `100644`, for a file that is not executable, or `100755`, for a file that is executable.<sup>2</sup>

There is also a *stage number*, which is normally just zero.  You can see all of these in `git ls-files --stage` output:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 c2f5fe385af1bbc161f6c010bdcf0048ab6671ed 0       .cirrus.yml
100644 c592dda681fecfaa6bf64fb3f539eafaf4123ed8 0       .clang-format
100644 42cdc4bbfb05934bb9c3ed2fe0e0d45212c32d7a 0       .editorconfig
100644 b08a1416d86012134f823fe51443f498f4911909 0       .gitattributes
```

(lots more omitted).

The default action for `git ls-files` is to list out those file names that are (a) in the index and (b) correspond to the current working directory or a subdirectory of it.  So for files that are in the current working directory *and* are also in the index, `git ls-files` will print those files' names.  For files that are in the current working directory, but are *not* in the index, `git ls-files` *won't* print those files' names:

> I created a new file `HelloWorld.cs` (and I didn't use `git add` to add this file) ...

When you `git checkout` some commit, Git fills the index *from* that commit.  So all the files that *are* in the commit, have copies in the index; files that *aren't* in the commit, don't.  Since the file `HelloWorld.cs` *wasn't* in the commit, it's not in the index.

You created the file, so it is now in your *work-tree* or *working tree*.  Here, you have files that you can see and work with; these files are in ordinary format, not a special Git-only format like the ones in the index.  But this file *isn't* in the index.

If you run `git add`, that tells Git: *Copy this file from the work-tree into the index.*  If it's already in the index, this process overwrites the index copy.  If not, it creates a new file in the index.  But you didn't do that either.

> then I run `git ls-files` and it didn't display `HelloWorld.cs`.

Since the default action of `git ls-files` is to display file names that *are* in the index, and `HelloWorld.cs` is *not* in the index, `git ls-files` won't display the file name now.

(Note that there are other modes of operation for `git ls-files`.  In particular, `git ls-files --other` tells the program to list files that *are* in the work-tree but *are not* in the index.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, what's in the index is not a *copy* of the file, but rather a *reference* to a Git *blob object*.  But this only matters if you start getting into low level `git ls-files --stage` and `git update-index` operations.  Mostly, you can just think of the index has holding copies of files, rather than references to copies.

<sup>2</sup>These resemble Linux `stat` mode bits because they are in fact Linux `stat` mode bits.  The `10000` part is the `S_IFREG` mode.  Symbolic links in the index have mode `120000`, which matches the `S_IFLNK` bits.  Git once supported additional permission bits, but this turned out to be a mistake, so now rw-r--r-- (644) and rwxr-xr-x (755) are the only ones allowed.  *Gitlink* entries also appear in the index and have mode `160000`, which is not a valid Linux file mode.  Directories never appear in the index, which is why Git won't store directories, but mode `40000` does appear in *tree* objects.